# could not autowire no beans of type found, for service in hybris

Tags: autowired, sap-commerce-cloud

```
<!-- Total Customer service dao facade-->
<bean id="totalCustomersDao"
      class="de.hybris.training.core.dao.impl.TotalCustomersDaoImpl">
    <property name="flexibleSearchService" ref="flexibleSearchService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="totalCustomerService" class=" de.hybris.training.core.impl.TotalCustomerServiceImpl">
    <property name="totalCustomersDao" ref="totalCustomersDao"/>
</bean>

<bean id="totalCustomerFacade" class="de.hybris.training.core.facade.impl.TotalCustomerFacadeImpl">
    <property name="totalCustomerService" ref="totalCustomerService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="usersFindJob" class=" de.hybris.training.core.job.UsersFindJob"
      parent="abstractJobPerformable" >

</bean>
```

this is xml.

This is facade class

```
public class TotalCustomerFacadeImpl implements TotalCustomerFacade {

//TODO autowired or resoucre not work

    private TotalCustomerService totalCustomerService ;

    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(UsersFindJob.class);

    public TotalCustomerService getTotalCustomerService() {
        return totalCustomerService;
    }

    public void setTotalCustomerService(TotalCustomerService totalCustomerService) {
        this.totalCustomerService = totalCustomerService;
    }
```

here for

```
   private TotalCustomerService totalCustomerService ;
```

when i put autorwired, it says

```
could not autowire no beans of type found
```

WHen i write `resource or resource(name=totalCustomerService)`

it gives null pointer.

this is serviceimpl

```
public class TotalCustomerServiceImpl implements TotalCustomerService {
    private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(UsersFindJob.class);

    @Autowired
    private TotalCustomersDao totalCustomersDao;

    public TotalCustomersDao getTotalCustomersDao() {
        return totalCustomersDao;
    }


    public void setTotalCustomersDao(TotalCustomersDao totalCustomersDao) {
        this.totalCustomersDao = totalCustomersDao;
    }  public List<CustomerModel> getAllCustomersNames (String name) {     LOG.info("***********************************");
        LOG.info("***********************************");
        LOG.info("*************************getAllCustomersNames::");
        LOG.info("***********************************");
        LOG.info("***********************************");


        List<CustomerModel> customerModels = totalCustomersDao.findAllCustomersFromDao( name);

        return customerModels;

    }
```

those are interfaces

```
public interface TotalCustomerService {

        List<CustomerModel> getAllCustomersNames (String name);


    }

public interface TotalCustomerFacade {



    List<String> findCustomerContainingName(String firstName);


}
```

how can i solve this?

the paths are they are all in

> de.hybris.training.core

divided like

- dao
- facade
- service

what can i do? I need to go for that service. I tried lots of times. added autowired. removed , let it without any annotations but still same.

Also this did not work

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("totalCustomerService")
    private TotalCustomerService totalCustomerService ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove whitespace! `class=" de.hybris.training`

Change

```
<bean id="totalCustomerService" class=" de.hybris.training.core.impl.TotalCustomerServiceImpl">
```

to

```
<bean id="totalCustomerService" class="de.hybris.training.core.impl.TotalCustomerServiceImpl">
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because of whitespace

```
class=" de.
```

here